# Server Errors in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Every morning I get an email from Apps Script saying this:

**Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Not found‏**

> Your script, Not found, has recently failed to finish successfully. A
>   summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers
>   for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure
>   notifications, click here.

When I click the link in the email, it tries fetching the triggers but returns another error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try
>   again.Dismiss

How do I get rid of these messages?

Comment: The related issue on the Google Apps Script issue tracker is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [topic about this problem](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1847) on the GAS issue tracker. Please star it to promote it to the support.

> How do I get rid of these messages?

Now a solution is to filter such messages in your email system or to wait when the GAS teams fixes it.